# Handle precision difference in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a piece of my query in Oracle that generates discrete percentile:

```
...
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9999) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY DURATION_COUNT) as PERCENTILE_9999_QTY,   
...
```

The data type of `PERCENTILE_9999_QTY` is `Number(8)`.

It works fine except in some cases I get this error:

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this
>   column

I prefer not to change the `Number(8)` data type. Is there a way to insure that the value fits into the `Number(8)` precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result cannot fit in your N(8) column then there's not much you can do except (a) raise an exception, or (b) put something else instead:

```
SELECT ...
   CASE
      WHEN PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9999)
           WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY DURATION_COUNT)
           < 100000000
      THEN PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9999)
           WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY DURATION_COUNT)
      ELSE NULL
   END as PERCENTILE_9999_QTY,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions111.htm#i1000913):

> This function takes as an argument any
>   numeric datatype or any nonnumeric
>   datatype that can be implicitly
>   converted to a numeric datatype. **The
>   function returns the same datatype as
>   the numeric datatype of the argument**.

If you want Number(8) as output you have to execute this function on a dataset that fits in NUMBER(8).